# поиск слов после определённой конструкции

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Товарищи доброго времени суток, вопрос по поводу поиска и вывода слов после некой словарной конструкции, например в документе есть слово "слово" и мне необходимо вытащить то, что лежит за ним в этой и следующей строке, пока что я сподобился только на такой вариант решения, но он очевидно не подходит.

```
 word = 'слово'
i=0
with open('2.doc') as file:
    for line in file:
        list_words = line.split()
        i=i+1
        if word in list_words:
            print(line, end='')
            break
```

после правки в соответствии с комментарием получается следующая конструкция

```
 import re

#text = "нанр 123"
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines()  # читаем его построчно

parse_text = re.findall(r'\d+', f)
print(*parse_text, sep='\n')
f.write('реквизит верхний// ' + *parse_text)
f.close()
```

[image: текст вроде такого, нужно считать то что написано в приложении]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос примеры данных и ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку регулярных выражений [`RE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Если предполагается поиск значительного объема "словарных" строк, то один из вариантов использование метода библиотеки `findall()`, осуществляющий сопоставление по маске.

```
import re

text = """some text before
word1: any other text
some line for word1
any other line
one more line
word2: any other text
some line for word2"""

parse_text = re.findall('([\w]+):\s?([\S ]+)\n([\S ]+)', text)
print(*parse_text, sep='\n')
```

Регулярное выражение: `([\w]+):\s?([\S ]+)\n([\S ]+)`. В круглых скобках в случае с `re.findall()` указываются блоки, из которых извлекаются данные. Первый компонент `([\w]+)` ,берет любые символы из интервала букв, цифр и знака подчеркивания `_`. Потом `:`, которое у нас в тексте отделяет первое слово от остальной строки. Далее два блока `([\S ]+)`, которые ищут все символы `\S`, которые не относятся к пробелам (пробел, новая строка, табуляция и т.д.) плюс пробел. `\n` — новая строка.

Результат будет в виде списка кортежей (слово, "то, что после слова" и следующая строка):

```
('word1', 'any other text', 'some line for word1')
('word2', 'any other text', 'some line for word2')
```

Пример с чтением из файла

Содержимое файла:

```
Уважаемый С.С.Б.

Приложение:
копии подписей жителей (__ подписей на __ листах)

Житель района
```

Обработка:

```
import re

with open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read()

parse_text = re.findall('([\w]+)\:\s?([\S ]*)\n([\S ]+)', text)
print(*parse_text, sep='\n')
```

Результат:

```
('Приложение', '', 'копии подписей жителей (__ подписей на __ листах)')
```

В этом есть один момент. Вижу, что Вы пытаетесь считывать `doc` файл. Его нужно предварительно сконвертировать в `txt`, либо в docx (но для его чтения нужны дополнительные библиотеки).

Comment: можете пожалуйста объяснить что значит регулярное выражение

Comment: Добавил описание того, что входит в регулярное выражение

Comment: ок это я понял, но тут же возникла следующая проблема, я воспользовался этим регулярным выражением для парсинга текстового файла - и к сожалению не смог его открыть и прочесть

Comment: Пример куска текста выложите, пожалуйста. Выше пример использования, который нужно уточнить по фактическому тексту. Поэтому рекомендуется ожидаемый результат прикладывать. Файл вообще большой по размеру?

Comment: Добавил пример с чтением из файла. Уточню его, когда приложите свой текст. Кстати, Вы пытаетесь считать `doc` файл?

Comment: добавил примерное письмо, нужно считать то, что находится после слова приложение, документов в приложении может быть много, но по хорошему считывать стоит только первую строку, форматы как .doc так и .docx, так и .txt

Comment: Обновил. Заменил первое включение `([\S ]+)` после `:` на вариант, когда оно может быть, а когда нет `([\S ]*)`

Comment: ок все отлично взлетело, но как я понимаю из описания регулярного выражения поиск начинается после знака : правильно? ([\w]+):\s?([\S ]*+)\n([\S ]+), тогда меняя двоеточие я могу варьировать поиск?

Comment: Нет. Поиск идет на совпадение всего выражения. Когда маска совпадает, то из нее вычленяются три зоны в круглых скобках `()`. Первая у Вас выдает Приложение, потом зона после `:`. Она пустая сейчас, хотя изначально Вы писали, что там что-то может быть. И последняя зона — строка после.

Answer (score 0):

Нечто вроде:

```
def word_read(in_file):
    word = ''
    while True:
        data = in_file.read(1)
        if data == '': return ''
            
        if data == ' ' : return word
        if data == '\n': return word
        word += data
    
copy_flag = False
start_copy = '<<<'
end_copy = '>>>'

in_file = open('in_text.txt','r')
out_file = open('out_text.txt', 'w')

while True:
    word = word_read(in_file)
    if word == '': break
    if word == start_copy: 
        copy_flag = True
        continue
    if word == end_copy: 
       copy_flag = False
       continue
    if copy_flag: 
       out_file.write(word)
       out_file.write(' ')

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: воспользовался Вашим примером заменив  word = 'приложение', к сожалению файл который сформировался оказался пуст

Comment: @PallNick Под виндой запускали? Попробуйте файл только из ASCII символов. Подозреваю - проблема в кодировках...  А для контроля, после вызова *word = word_read(in_file)* добавьте печать *print(word)*  - станет понятно, в чём проблема.